# Calculate indices from a vector of vec3 objects by finding duplicate vertices

Tags: c++, opengl, glm-math, wavefront

I am trying to build an .obj file importer that renders said model to the screen.
At present I have imported the vertices and they are stored in a

```
std::vector<vec3> vertices;
```

My renderer class quite large so I'll link github instead of posting it here.

https://github.com/rob-DEV/OpenGL-Model-Viewer/blob/master/OpenGL-Model-Viewer/src/graphics/renderer/renderer.cpp

So at line 41 in renderer.cpp. I submit these vertexs to the renderer. Originally I just drew triangles, but I would like to take advantage of GL_ELEMENTS

My question is how (if possible) can I calculate these indices from a list of vertices? I have tried to find duplicates and do so when the model is loaded but i don't know how to map them.

Comment: I suppose you could use the assimp library and have it do this for you.  Though I understand doing it yourself is a good learning experience.

Comment: You need to include the relevant parts of your code in the question.  As it is, this lacks a [mcve].

Comment: I&#39;ve literally linked the entire renderer and pointed to the revelant line shown what I want addressed. I have shown the entire rendering process. Why are half the people on this site so obnoxious?!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Using mapped buffers (by `glMapBuffer`) does not work in your case.

For example, if you want to know if a vertex has been already mapped (a duplicate) you should read all of currently mapped vertices, which is slow.

If you want to use a sorted array (so fast binary search can be used) then many portions of that mapped buffer must be re-written during the sorting/storing process. Slow too.

A better option is to build your sorted vertices array on your own, on normal RAM. Be adviced of searching issues due to numerical matters when comparing two floats.

On a second pass each index is just the position of the current vertex. Same advice for numerical issues.

Data can be sent to the GPU by two simple `glBufferSubData`, one for vertices (and their colors and normals and etc) and another one for the indices.

If the object moves (and you prefer to update coordinates instead of use a translation matrix) then it's right to use a mapped buffer with new coordinates (as you currently do). Indices don't change, so they don't need to be updated.